# AWS Ec2 ubuntu run npm installs hangs which causes cpu utilization % shot up to 99%

Tags: npm, amazon-ec2

So I tried to run `npm install` for my react application in ec2 instance. However, when it ran to `reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted`, the system hung, and CPU % went up to 99%. So I tried to use `npm i --no-optional` to avoid `fsevents`. But this time, the system hung at `reify:@adobe/css-tools: sill audit bulk request` which also made 99% cpu utilization. I've never run into such problem before. Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: which EC2 instance are you using?